# Yii: adding custom fields

Tags: yii, custom-attributes

Is there a simple way of adding custom fields to a model? Say I have a table "user" with 3 fields: id, name and surname. I want this:

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk(1);
$echo $user->fullName; // echoes name and surname
```

Please note: I want this custom field to be added via sql, smth like

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->select = 'CONCAT("user".name, "user".surname) as fullName'; 
$user = User::model()->find($c);
```

Problem is that fullName property is not set.

**UPD**:

here is the code for a little bit trickier problem -- custom field from another table. This is how it's done:

```
    $model = Application::model();
    $model->getMetaData()->columns = array_merge($model->getMetaData()->columns, array('fullName' => 'CONCAT("u".name, "u".surname)'));

    $c = new CDbCriteria();
    $c->select = 'CONCAT("u".name, "u".surname) as fullName';
    $c->join = ' left join "user" "u" on "t".responsible_manager_id = "u".id';

    $model->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith($c);

    foreach ($model->findAll() as $o) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($o->fullName);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Comment: Pretty hacky solution though... I don't think that manually changing meta data is good style.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a function to the User class:

```
public function getFullName() { return $this->name.' '.$this->surname; }
```

This will return the full name as if it were an attribute from the database.  This is much easier than adding a calculated column to the SQL.

Comment: With Yii's __get methods, you can call that function just like it was a regular column too: `$user->fullName`

Comment: When you write something like `$user->fullName`, fullName can be part of $user for a few different reasons.  It could be a member variable of the User active record, it could be a column in the User table, it could be the name of a relation that User has, it could be a member function named getFullName().  I think that is all and in the order they are checked.

Comment: Translating $user->fullName to $user->getFullName() is part of CComponent, the base class for all Yii classes. For ActiveRecord, additional attribute/relation checks are done FIRST: http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.9/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#133

Answer (score 0):

In model

```
public function getMetaData(){
        $data = parent::getMetaData();
        $data->columns['fullName'] = array('name' => 'fullName');
        return $data;
    }
```

Thus not recommended